# Mousemove To Deviceorientation (Accelerometer)

Tags: javascript, 3d, parallax

I have parallax scene which works with mouse movement, i want to enable device orientation (Accelerometer) in my scrips so the parallax effect works on devices aswell.

But It's very tricky i can't figure out how to modify this script to add deviceorientation to it. Can you please have a look.

[JSFIDDLE](https://goo.gl/8MXogq)

PS: You can simulate Device-orientation in chrome!

The tutorial how to create this parallax scene is [HERE](https://codyhouse.co/gem/parallax-hero-image/)

Comment: What exactly did you mean with device orientation?

Answer (score 0):

to add deviceorientation to your script you should be able to hook on the deviceorientation event, by registering **deviceorientation** event listener.Here is a simple code that illustrates this process.

for your case just add the code below to your demo and customize the code to be executed when  device orientation is changed:

```
        //check if the browser supports the device orientation event   
               if(window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
                  console.log("Browser supports the device orientation");
                  //registering deviceorientation event listener
                  window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", process, false);
                } else {
                  // The browser does not support the device orientation event
                   console.log("Browser does not support the device orientation");
                }

            function process(event) {
             //put the code to be executed when  device orientation is changed
              console.log("Device Orientation changed");
              var alpha = event.alpha;
              var beta = event.beta;
              var gamma = event.gamma;
              console.log("Alpha : " + alpha + "Beta : " + beta + "Gamma : " + gamma ); 
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but i already know how to use deviceorientation event in javascript...my question is about making it work with my script.
This is a bit tricky...for example mousemove event returns from 0 to browser width but deviceorientation even returns -90 to +90...i can't figure out a solution for this????

Comment: @user3704796 can you explain how you use device orientation, because in your jsfiddle it not appear